# Let $ P=X^3 + 2X +2 \in \Bbb Z_3[X]$. Find out if $P$ can be reduced.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

> Let $ P=X^3 + 2X +2 \in \Bbb Z_3[X]$. Find out if $P$ can be reduced.

I've found out that in $\Bbb Z_3$ the polynomial $P$ doesn't have any roots, but this yet doesn't imply that $P$ is not reducible. Suppose that $P=DQ$. Now $$\deg(P)=\deg(DQ)=\deg(D)+ \deg(Q).$$ Since $P$ is of degree $3$ either $\deg(D)=1, \deg(Q)=2$ or the other way around. It seems that we can suppose wlog that $\deg(D)=1$(?).
Then $D=aX+b$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb Z_3$. Now I've found out that every $1$ degree polynomial has a root, but don't know yet why is this true. If so, then the root of $D$ is $-a^{-1}b$ and so $D(-a^{-1}b)=0$. Now as $\Bbb Z_3$ is commutative ring we have that $$P(-a^{-1}b)=(D \cdot Q)(-a^{-1}b)= D(-a^{-1}b)Q(-a^{-1}b)=0 \cdot Q(-a^{-1}b)= 0$$  but this is a contradiction as $P$ doesn't have any roots in $\Bbb Z_3$.

> Where does the result come from that a first degree polynomial always has a root?

Comment: Over any field, a cubic polynomial is irreducible if and only if it has no roots on that field.

Comment: So are you saying that I could have deduced that this polynomial is irreducible just by noting that in $\Bbb Z_3$ it has no roots? I was instructed no to do this and told that a polynomial can be reducible even though it has no roots. @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: Can you provide an example? I can prove that what I wrote is true.

Comment: @Jen If $f$ is a degree $3$ polynomial, then a factorization of it will be of the form $(x-\alpha)g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is a degree $2$ polynomial. So, if $f$ has no roots in the field, then we cannot pull out that linear factor. For polynomials of higher degree, this is not true. For example, if $h$ is a degree $4$ polynomial with no roots in the field, it still may be factorable into $h_1(x)h_2(x)$, where $h_1, h_2$ are both degree $2$ polynomials.

Answer (score -1):

Any first degree polynomial can be written as $aX+b$. This clearly has a root equal to $-b/a$, or in other words $-a^{-1}b$, where taking the inverse is possible because we are working over a field.